# An unexpected I/O error has occured during installation of windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, installation

I have Dell inspiron n4050 laptop. Pre loaded with windows 7 basic (64-bit). I want to install windows 8 but it gives error before setup starts. Error says..

---

Recovery

There was a problem with a device connected to your PC

An unexpected I/O error has occurred.

Error code: 0xc00000e9

This problem can happen when a removable storage device is removed while it's in use or is failing. Properly connecting any removable storage and resatring your PC may fix this problem.

---

No device connected to PC at this stage. I'm installing windows 8 pro from DVD drive. I've tweak BIOS but not succeeded (Restore all default BIOS settings).

Can anyone tell me how to solve this error?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Ensure all external devices are unplugged, and confirm there's no SD card in the card reader slot. If that doesn't help, try transferring Win8 Setup to a USB stick and use that instead. As a bonus should be much faster than the DVD too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's likely the disk you are installing from is bad/scratched or the CD/DVD drive is failing/going bad. You will find that some DVD/CD drives are more "picky" than others... if you have a spare, can borrow a friends for the install, or an external USB one, give it a try.

Comment: Installing via USB done the thing... Thanks for the answer..

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem trying to install Windows 7 from a DVD where I had burned an ISO of the Windows 7 installation (downloaded directly from Microsoft as an ISO).  I was trying to install Windows onto a brand new HDD.

The computer kept giving me that exact same error - there was nothing plugged in at all (I even unplugged the keyboard).

Turns out it was the installation disk.  I tried a different copy of the disk and it worked just fine.  So it was some problem with the way the ISO was written to disk (in my case).

Therefore - SnakeDoc had the answer first.  I am just adding my answer by way of confirmation.